# Why a dict type variable content cannot be pickled?

Tags: python, pickle, numba

I have to use the numba's dict (numba.typed.typeddict.Dict) type to define a dictionary:

```
@njit
def init_numba_dict():
    x = numpy.array([0], dtype=numpy.int32)
    return {"01234-5": x[0], "0-1": x[0]}

myDict = init_numba_dict()
```

Now I need to save it to a file. I thought the following code shall work:

```
import pickle
filehandler = open("file.dat", 'wb') 
pickle.dump(myDict , filehandler, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
filehandler.close()
```

I got this error: "TypeError: can't pickle _nrt_python._MemInfo objects"

Any hint? How can I save and restorethe content of a numba.typed.typeddict.Dict to a file?

Comment: For reference: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) is what can and cannot be pickled.

Comment: You may able to just pickle the data portion follow instructions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) although I'm not sure because I haven't tried it.

Comment: I suppose the MemInfo objects are not pure Python, but are implemented in C and manage resources (e.g. memory) in such a way that they can't be reasonably unpickled elsewhere. Export the data into a more portable format.

Comment: the dict type variable _can_ be pickled, but not the contents, in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. I just faced the same error and found the solution. The error occurs because numba (C language) returns a pointer instead of values like python in term of array or dict. On the other hand, pickle is asking for an python object as input. So, all you need to do is to change the numba dict to an python dict object before pickling it using dict() function.

```
import pickle
filehandler = open("file.dat", 'wb') 
pickle.dump(dict(myDict), filehandler, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
filehandler.close()
```